# Can we get SVG support? Do we need it?

Tags: feature-request, images

Now that the logo is SVG, any chance we can get an option to post svg images. In many cases this would make life much easier.

Is the problem related somehow to the open ended nature of SVG itself? Are scripts the problem?

Comment: Just curious, how would it make things easier?

Comment: @Scott I wouldnt need to host my own one off demos, vector resources.

Comment: Oh, are you linking to SVG files now? In what questions?

Comment: @Scott No, i came to the conclusion it was not worth it. But it would make sense to post vector images when questions are vector related.

Comment: @Scott see the problem is I can not guarantee availability for the images the same way as imgur does. Apparently this is a quite much requested feature, even on imgur.

Comment: I'm not opposed to it, I just don't see any real need for it. In apps sure SVG is preferred, but here, where you're merely answering questions, do you *really* want to give away SVG images to people for free?

Comment: @Scott Im a mechanical engineer my drawings are for some reason not protected by copyright :) So i wouldnt know as im allways giving stuff like this for free, but not without a fee per see.

Comment: Just came here to ask this very question. I'd really like it if we could implement SVG uploads with the SE tool.

Comment: @SOIA see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230919/why-not-svg-capable-editor?lq=1 and comment by Paul for an example of answers which are harder because of needing to use bitmap images. For my own part, I would have used SVG [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/8822/108) in order to make the text legible and not have to link through to larger image. The graphic in [this answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/11674/108) is illegible. It's a chicken and egg thing. Svg isn't being used because it's not supported (in a stable non-link breaking way).

Comment: @SOIA give my svg away for free? Absolutely. To the same limits and extent I right now give away my words and code and images. They're snippets, not products.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can already post SVG images, but you can't upload them. Here's an example

```
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg" width="256">
```

[image]

Since Stack Exchange [outsources their image hosting to imgur](http://stack.imgur.com/), I'm not sure how much control the devs will have over this (though I would love to have it!)

Comment: Yes i know i can host my own stuff, its just that any small server slice can eat a lot of my own resources for no good. I am sure some others would feel it would add to the completeness. Anyway im sure the site devs have more resources than many of us in this department.

Answer (score 2):

There is a long standing feature request to ImgUr to add SVG to image types but so far it doesn't seem to have grabbed the right attention or any traction. This affects all Stack sites, I'm aware of the issue/need because of my work on other sites in the network, but perhaps here on Graphic Design there's the necessary concentration of SVG folk to find or build a solution.

- Meta SE - [Allow SVG image uploads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92568/allow-svg-image-uploads)
- Imgur community - [Native SVG support](https://community.imgur.com/t/native-svg-support-on-imgur/11369) request

Until ImgUr and/or Stack developers see the benefit of SVG (please go add your voice) what other public and stable service can we use for this?

Answer (score -1):

This is a test to see if dumping [the code of an SVG into JSBin](http://jsbin.com/defifasi/1/edit), in this case the [snap svg](http://snapsvg.io/) crocodile, then `<img src="`ing the output page works:

Darn, doesn't work. Seems JSBin forces `<html>` etc around the output even if it's removed. Oh well. Will leave this answer here to save time for anyone else with the same idea.